# Maven minor version `x`

Tags: java, maven

I've come across this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigtable</groupId>
  <artifactId>bigtable-hbase-1.x</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

When I try to do:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigtable</groupId>
  <artifactId>bigtable-hbase-2.x</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I get an error that:

> 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.google.cloud.bigtable:bigtable-hbase-2.x:jar is missing

What is the meaning of the `x` - is it some kind of wildcard? If so, why does 1.x not require a version, whereas 2.x does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are two orthogonal issues:

1. `bigtable-hbase-2.x` vs `bigtable-hbase-1.x` are just names (strings) as far as maven is concerned. It doesn't understand anything about `1.x` and `2.x`. It certainly doesn't understand `x`.
2. You need a `version` for every `dependency`, unless it's specified in a `dependencyManagement` section. It looks like you have a `dependencyManagement` section somewhere in your (parent?) pm. But that dependencyManagement only covers `bigtable-hbase-1.x`, not `bigtable-hbase-2.x`

Comment: These artifact names relate to supporting either the HBase 1.* set of APIs, or 2.* APIs.  `bigtable-hbase-1.x` works with HBase 1, `bigtable-hbase-2.x` works with HBase 2.*.  We couldn't use `*` in the name, so we used `x`.

Comment: The key difference between HBase 1.* and HBase 2.* is that HBase 2.* has an async API.  There are some subtle differences between the two APIs, which is why we couldn't support both 1.* and 2.* in the same artifact.